# Select an option in website's mobile version (responsive mode)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, responsive-design, html-select

How can I select a size option from https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile#products/305278, when I'm browsing it in responsive mode? I tried it with `document.querySelector("#size-options > option:nth-child(2)").selected = "selected";` but it doesn't work.

In desktop mode https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/pants/n1to4psjk/wlmx7p5hr the method `document.querySelector("#size > option:nth-child(3)").selected = "selected";` works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the element id? It looks like the id is different in mobile view. Try id `size-options` instead of `size`

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it, I used different ids on mobile and desktop version, if you continue to checkout there are also options like country, card type etc. and those doesn’t work either.

Comment: Actually it is infact changing - just not getting reflected in UI. After running the statement that you have posted, try running `document.querySelector("#size-options > option:nth-child(2)").selected` and it will return `true`. UI is not getting updated, yes. 
What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I’m making a bot which autobuys products, so you pre-define the item’s name, color, size and the bot should add an item with those parameters to cart. In the checkout page it autofills pre-defined order details like shipping country etc.

Comment: Then this should work as it is since the size change is really happening behind the scenes. If you want to make sure the event is really registered and want to update the UI as well, then try triggering a event, after the above code is run. If you're using Jquery, try `$("#size-options").trigger('change')`.

Comment: I’m not using Jquery, but I will try it somehow else and let  you know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`document.querySelector("#order_billing_country").value = "countryCode";`
and it will work on both desktop and mobile.
The UI on mobile never gets updated, but when you press process payment, the right value is sent to Supreme.